# Javascript push into array by index while looping through it

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [{
                        date : "2016/1/26",
                        count: 6
                    },
                    {
                        date : "2016/1/31",
                        count: 2
                    },
                    {
                        date : "2016/2/2",
                        count: 4
                    }]
```

I need to have all the dates (each day) inside the array from the current minimal date to the  current max date. If the day does not exist, i need to add a new object with count=0.

The array is already sorted by date.

In my example, the array should be converted to:

```
arr = [{
        date : "2016/1/26",
        count: 6
    },
               {
        date : "2016/1/27",
        count: 0
    },
    {
        date : "2016/1/28",
        count: 0
    },
    {
        date : "2016/1/29",
        count: 0
    },
    {
        date : "2016/1/30",
        count: 0
    },
    {
        date : "2016/1/31",
        count: 2
    },
    {
        date : "2016/2/1",
        count: 0
    },
    {
        date : "2016/2/2",
        count: 4
    }]
```

My approach:

```
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) { 

                    var prev = new Date(arr[i].date);
                    var next = new Date(arr[i+1].date);

                    if (prev.setTime(prev.getTime() + 86400000) != next) {
                        //86400000 equals a day in miliseconds

                        arr.splice(i+1, 0, {date: prev, count: 0});

                    }

      }
```

This makes an infinite loop? The website gets stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with a loop in the loop.

```js
var arr = [{ date: "2016/1/26", count: 6 }, { date: "2016/1/31", count: 2 }, { date: "2016/2/2", count: 4 }],
    result = function (array) {
        var r = [],
            min = new Date(arr[0].date);

        array.forEach(function (a) {
            var aDate= new Date(a.date);
            while (min < aDate) {
                r.push({ date: min.getFullYear() + '/' + (min.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + min.getDate(), count: 0 });
                min.setTime(min.getTime() + 86400000);
            }
            r.push(a);
            min.setTime(aDate.getTime() + 86400000);
        });
        return r;
    }(arr);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Another attempt with an object for counting and two loops. I works for unsorted data.

```js
var arr = [{ date: "2016/1/26", count: 6 }, { date: "2016/1/31", count: 2 }, { date: "2016/2/2", count: 4 }],
    result = function (array) {
        var r = [],
            min = new Date(arr[0].date),
            max = new Date(arr[0].date),
            object = {},
            d;

        array.forEach(function (a) {
            var x = new Date(a.date);
            if (!object[a.date]) {
                object[a.date] = { date: a.date, count: 0 };
                if (x < min) {
                    min = x;
                }
                if (x > max) {
                    max = x;
                }
            }
            object[a.date].count += a.count;
        });
        while (min <= max) {
            d = min.getFullYear() + '/' + (min.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + min.getDate();
            r.push(object[d] || { date: d, count: 0 });
            min.setTime(min.getTime() + 86400000);
        }
        return r;
    }(arr);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your comparison operator between the previous date + 1 day and the next date : they are always different ! Try to add some `console.log()` in your code and you will see. As you only consider days here, you should extract from `prev` and `next` the day, month and year and compare this.

To do so, you can for example use the `toDateString` function or, instead of adding 1 day to your `prev` variable, compute the difference between `prev` and `next` and see if it's greater than one day or not.

Comment: You are right. But if I do that I am only adding one day for each gap between days. In my example I would only add 2016/1/27 and 2016/2/1, because the new objects are not being processed in the loop.

Comment: Ha ok, it just struck me as obvious the reason for your infinite loop and only took a glance at your code. I'll edit considering this.

Comment: Edit made, the problem was not at all what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Date is an object in Javascript, when you compare them with equal it compares the references to the objects. Use date.getTime() or +(date) to get a value you can compare.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is always true, because you are comparing two distinct date objects. Even though they might represent the same date, as they are different objects, they are considered not equal.

Here is some code that does the date-gap-filling you are looking for:

```js
// date formatter
function dateFmt(dt) {
    return dt.getFullYear() + '/' + (dt.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dt.getDay();
}

// main function
function fillDateGaps(arr) {
    if (!arr.length) return; // detect invalid input
    var result = [];
    var i = 0;
    var arrDate = new Date(arr[0].date);
    var curDate = arrDate;
    while (true) {
        var obj = { date: dateFmt(curDate), count: 0 };
        result.push(obj);
        if (arrDate.getDate() === curDate.getDate()) {
            console.log(arrDate, i);
            obj.count = arr[i].count;
            i++;
            if (i >= arr.length) break; // all done
            arrDate = new Date(arr[i].date);
        }
        curDate.setDate(curDate.getDate()+1);
        console.log('cur', curDate);
    }
    return result;
}

// example data
var arr = [{
    date : "2016/1/26",
    count: 6
},
{
    date : "2016/1/31",
    count: 2
},
{
    date : "2016/2/2",
    count: 4
}];

// call function
var result = fillDateGaps(arr);

// Snippet: output result in readable format
document.write ('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```